# Is it possible to create a Super Soldier based on the following ways?

Tags: internal-consistency

1. Is it possible to create a "Super soldier" by artificially creating and implanting a device in the hosts body that would pump or increase the amount of adrenaline released in the Host's body exponentially?
2. If so can there be a way the Soldier can control the device on when to activate it or not? And by control I don't mean like a "physical switch" but more like "conscious switch". So, that the Soldier is not always in a "powered-up" state. He has the choice to activate it or not.
3. How is it possible to increase the soldiers muscle mass slightly to increase his physical strength, durability and endurance? Is it possible via pumping steroids?

Comment: What is your definition of a super solider?  In most situations, an overdose of adrenaline is detrimental compared to the measured amount a well trained solder's body will produce.  Very very rarely in combat do you want to be out of balance in any way, including chemically.

Comment: Not ethically. Expect many dead "super soldiers" followed by some that are very ill. Many attempts will be needed to improve performance.

Comment: What's the goal of the 'super soldier'? Punch through tank armor? Jump high enough to grab onto aircraft? Nimble enough to dodge rifle bullets? Perceptive enough to hear frequency-hopping radio? Clever enough to decrypt enemy signals?

Answer (score 1):

You could theoretically implant a device into the brain of you super soldier candidate that agonized the neurotransmitters for adrenaline, giving the soldier a boost. You could wire that chip to another part of the brain, allowing it to be flipped on and off with a thought. We already have implants that let us send basic signals, like turning the lights on and off, by thought. See [How to switch on a light with your mind](http://drdavidhamilton.com/how-to-switch-on-a-light-with-your-mind/) for more information.

How effective this would make a super soldier is up for debate, because while adrenaline gives you strength and pain resistance, it also gives you tunnel vision, making it not the best for fighting enemies from all sides and when it wears off, the soldier would feel effects similar to that of coming down off any stimulant, the effects of the battle hitting them harder. It would basically only be good for short engagements with guaranteed support afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it, but the payoff is high:

Whenever you pull this trick off you burdening your heart furthermore, the long term effects will include:

- Cardiac Arrest, AKA: The reason why to not choose sports as a life
  career, unless you want to die horrible deaths.
- Exhaustion beyond any reasonable measure.

Also, why'd you do it? This is a natural stuff, that will always kick in, whenever your life is threatened.

If you seek to increase stamina, my best recommendation is to ask questions about an "[ATP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adenosine_triphosphate) replenishing, and Lactic acid filtering device."

Answer (score 1):

1) Can such a device be made? Sure why not but it won't neccesarily help to create a better soldier.

2) Sure, we're getting much better and brain-computer interfaces. If we can make a chip that lets you control a robotic hand with your brain we can make a chip that moves a switch in your brain.

3) Yes? For increased muscle mass you can suppress the myostatin gene. This of course requires to be done before birth. But this will lead to greatly increased muscle mass.
This won't help you with endurace though. For that you might want to look at lactic acid breakdown. By creating a more efficient lactic acid breakdown you will reduce muscle fatigue. Do this enough and you could theoretically eliminate ot all together.